# How to condition segues using CloudKit query?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, segue, cloudkit

I created a login page backed up by CloudKit. 
I want to know how to create a conditioned segue if the login has a certain value, and then direct the user to a View Controller based on that value

In details, I have three Segues I want to connect:

> sign in id segue:`LoginSuccessSegue`
>
> staff tab bar id segue:`idStaffTabBar`
>
> student tab bar id segue:`idStudentTabBar`

First Segue
**`LoginSuccessSegue`**:
the sign in view controller has a show segue id LoginSuccessSegue the connects to staff tab bar controller and student tab bar controller.

Second Segue
**`idStaffTabBar`**:
After `queryProfileType()` is executed, it will look for the profile type in a list to check if the user profile is a teacher value or something else. Then if that is true "LoginSuccessSegue" will automatically take the user to staff tab bar controller, "StaffBookedVC.self" by using`its segue`idStaffTabBar `

Third Segue 
**`idStudentTabBar`**:
if the user is not a teacher then after pressing the sign in button redirect to student tab bar controller, "stdBookingVC.self" by using idStudentTabBar or

> How can I achieve an automatic conditional sign in in multiple views suing segues and cloud kit query?

This is the code for the sign-in button:

```
@IBAction func btnSignInTapped(sender: UIButton)
{
    let userEmailAddress = userEmailAddressTextField.text
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text


    if(userEmailAddress!.isEmpty || userPassword!.isEmpty)
    {
        notifyUser("Empty fields", message: "all fields are required")
    }
    print("fetching is in progress")

    queryProfileType()

    print("\nfetching had stopped")
}//end of signInbtn

func queryProfileType()
{
    queryCredentials()

    print("\nProfile Query starting")
    //execute query
    let organizers = ["Teacher || Youtuber || Instagrammer || "]
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ProfileType = '\(organizers)' ")
    print("\nThis is the predicate\n\(predicate)")
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "RegisteredAccounts", predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase!.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { results, error in
        if (error != nil)
        {
            print(error)
        }else
            {

                if (results! == organizers)
                {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idStaffTabBar", sender: StaffBookedVC.self)
                }else{
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idStudentTabBar", sender: stdBookingVC.self)

                }
                print("\(results)\nthese are the printed results")
            }

        }
    let firstFetch = CKFetchRecordsOperation()
    let secondFetch = CKFetchRecordsOperation()
    secondFetch.addDependency(firstFetch)

    let queue = NSOperationQueue()
    queue.addOperations([firstFetch, secondFetch], waitUntilFinished: false)
}
```

here is a picture of the storyboard segues [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ezwG.png)

if your answer will contain these methods, please show me some examples:
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and prepareForSegue

this did not work from me either

```
self.presentViewController(SignInNavigationVCTabBars, animated: true,
                { results, error in

                if (results! == organizers)
                {
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idStaffTabBar", sender: StaffUITABbarVC.self)

                }else{
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idStudentTabBar", sender: StdUITABbarVC.self)

                }
            }
```

`

Comment: Not clear about the question itself. But the way you are doing is correct. Depend on different condition, you will call `performSegueWithIdentifier` with different Identifiers

Comment: the program stops at the conditions. if there is any one who can help, please share your answer

Comment: You need debug where the program stops, stops at the condition? Stops at ViewController change? Stops at segue?. Try set a break point in the prepareForSegue.

Comment: This is the bug : `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<appname.MasterViewController: 0x7d27d7a0>) has no segue with identifier 'idStudentTabBar''
*** First throw call stack:`                                                                            >is it because in this [my storybaord](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9ezwG.png) does not see the navigation controller between the master view and the tab bars views?

Comment: Your storyboard does not have a view with the id idStudentTabBar. Make sure you have that set.

Comment: Edwin Vermeer Actually it does have it. [link] (https://www.evernote.com/shard/s267/sh/12701a90-0c84-4013-b37f-8743e80dfc77/9376f182669a59fcbdc4ed3bc1334eaa)

Comment: does it have to do with the fetching order ?

Comment: The issue here is 'performSegueWithIdentifier' can not perform the sugue from the current view controller, while in your case, the segue with `id` is linked from the navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer

> I did not expect valueforkey would have it all 
>   what can I see? never stop trying

```
 //log in function
func queryCredentials()
{
    print("*********\nQueryCredentials starting")

    // System indicator
    let spinningActivity = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
    spinningActivity.labelText = "Signing in"
    spinningActivity.detailsLabelText = "Please wait"


    // querying predicate in cloud kit to check via email and password property
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Email = %@", userEmailAddressTextField.text!)
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "RegisteredAccounts", predicate: predicate)
    publicDatabase?.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil,
        completionHandler: ({results, error in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                    {
                    // if the user is not signed, display this error
                    self.notifyUser("Cloud Access Error",
                        message: "to fix this error Sign in you icloud \n go to settings\nthen sign in icloud account\n error code:\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
            }else
            {
                if (results!.count > 0)
                {
                    // the results after success case of the query
                    let record = results![0] as! CKRecord

                    // read from the result to navigate via profiletype attribute
                    let proftype = record.valueForKey("ProfileType") as! String

                    switch proftype
                    {
                    case("Teacher"):
                        self.staffView()
                        break;

                    case("Manager"):
                        self.staffView()
                        break;

                    case("Student"):
                        // stdView() is a student coded segue as a function to navigate to student view
                        self.stdView()
                        break;

                    case("Worker"):
                        self.stdView()
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                    }
                    self.currentRecord = record

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                        {
                        // if credentials are correct, display you are logged in
                        self.userPasswordTextField!.text =
                            record.objectForKey("Password") as! String
                        self.notifyUser("Welcome", message: "You are loogedin")

                        }
                }else
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
                        {
                        self.notifyUser("No Match Found",
                            message: "No record matching")
                        }
                }
            }

        }))
    // hiding indicator
    spinningActivity.hide(true)
}
```

Comment: I deleted the navigation bar and added the staff segue = self.staffView()     and the student segue self.stdView() to the login page. valueforkey will read the proftype from cloud kit, then navigate to the segues

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like `presentModalViewController` to show the `navigationController` first, within your `queryProfileType` method. And then do some smart logic to determine which route to go, after the `navigationController` is loaded. So a custom `UINavigationController` is needed.

Or an *easier* way:

Move your `loginViewController` into the navigation controller stack, and then link the two existing segues, i.e. `idStaffTabBar` and `idStudentTabBar` to it. That will solve the problem.

Comment: what if I add the queryProfileType in the customized navigation controller class? Do you think that would work ?

Comment: That's not really a good idea. You want to stay on the login view if the login failed, which I believe is the functionality of `queryCredentials`. What prevent you from moving the login screen to the 'right' of navigation controller?

Comment: `self.presentViewController(navigationController:SignInNavigationVCTabBars, animated: true, completion: nil)` says:  Cannot convert value of type 'SignInNavigationVCTabBars.Type' to expected argument type 'UIViewController'

Comment: `SignInNavigationVCTabBars` is not a `NavigationController`